# Does JavaFX always use pixels?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I am a beginner in JavaFX. All I have created so far is a window with an image in it and scrolling text. However, what I observed is that everything was specified in pixels. From node positions to stage width and height.

Now, Swing has `GridBagLayout` with the `GridBagConstraints` which allow me to create the layout in a resolution-independent way. Is there any such option in JavaFX ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at a whole set of [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) descendants: AnchorPane, BorderPane, FlowPane, GridPane, HBox, StackPane, TilePane, VBox

They all are layout managers to handle pixels for you.

Comment: So, is it a bad practice to mess with the `Scene` width and height in pixels? From a Swing POV, it was recommended to use `pack()` instead of `setSize()`

Comment: If you have fixed layout you may just put your items on a `Scene` and let FX calculate how large your Scene and Stage should be. If you have more dynamic in your app you may want to control Stage width and height manually, it's ok too.

Comment: but then the application will look small / large on different screen right ? :)

Comment: yep, but standard controls (buttons, test, etc) wouldn't scale anyway, so it doesn't matter. E.g. look at windows calculator -- do you expect it to has huge number buttons on 1900*1600 monitor? What would be kinda scary.

Comment: My aim is to have a proportional size across all resolutions, that's all :)

Comment: FX doesn't help that from the box. You need to add you own logic which will scale app based on user's monitor resolution.

Comment: Ouch ! Soon to be fixed in JavaFX 3 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39089/discussion-between-sergey-grinev-and-little-child)

Comment: MigLayout (which has a version for fx) supports resolution-independent sizes, the unit is named "logical pixel" and even is the default (? not entirely certain about that)